# How Can I Make A Working .py File Within a Python File?

Tags: python, file, file-handling

I am trying to make the file py.py within this code

```
def makeFile():
    contents = "import JustIRC\nimport requests";
    file = open('py.py');
    file.write(contents);
    file.close();
```

But if I run it it returns `io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable` What is the problem and how can I fix it? I need to be able to specifically tab and newline for the program to run correctly

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file with the write option:

```py
file = open("py.py", "w")
```

Comment: It's also worth using `with open("py.py", "w") as file` to automatically close the file without calling `file.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to use that file:
`file = open('py.py', 'w')` - create the file if it doesn't exist and write to it. If the file exists, delete everything from it and write the new content
`file = open('py.py', 'a')` - create the file if it doesn't exists. If the file exists, keep the content and write at the end